# Why citizens are unhappy?

Tags: cities-skylines

I clicked on a residential builder randomly and noticed there were unhappy citizens, as shown on the picture above.

[image]

However, there is no indication why those citizen are unhappy. Can anyone explain how to obtain this information?

Comment: It might be because the low education rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their house might be located too close to the industrial area or very loudy/dirty building(s).
Also could be because of low education As @ardaozkal mentioned.
Check appropriate layer maps to see if they get services they need.